# Angular 5 and && operator

Tags: angular

Hi I have not been able to find a definitive answer as to if the && operator works in Angular templates... I am trying to do something like things

```
<div *ngIf="obj.type === 'Selection' && obj.label === 'Item1'">
```

Comment: Yes, it works. Did you find a case where it doesn't?

Comment: The only reason the above should throw an exception/error is if `obj` is null or undefined. To avoid that add either an additional check on `obj` **or** use the `?.` operator. `*ngIf="obj?.type === 'Selection' && obj.label === 'Item1'"` (you only need it once as if it is undefined/null the first check will return false and the second condition check won't execute).

Comment: @Igor thanks for the tip...

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your ngIf and it works after i made sure that the obj is initialized, below is my working code

**HTML component**

```
<input id="input1" name="input1" [(ngModel)]="obj.label" type="text" #input1="ngModel" />
<input id="input2" name="input2" [(ngModel)]="obj.type" type="text" #input2="ngModel" />

<div *ngIf="obj.type === 'Selection' && obj.label === 'Item1'">
    <label>It works</label>
</div>
```

**Modal Component**

```
obj:testclass = new testclass();
```

**Class**

```
export class testclass{
  label:string;
  type:string;
}
```

I guess your problem was that the obj is null or undefined.

If you could post a sample code with your issue so any one can debug your issue will be great.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

There might be an issue because 'obj' didn't contain any value or its undefined.
So restricting validation will solve your problem

```
<div *ngIf="obj && obj.type === 'Selection' && obj.label === 'Item1'">
```